# Angular Back Navigation

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have 2 sibling components. Between those the routing works as expected but when navigating back I want to reach the parent component of both, regardless of which of the sibling-components I'm on.

**parent module:**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: "",
                component: ListeMonitorComponent,
            },

            {
                path: "webview/:id",
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import("~/app/monitordaten/webview/webview.module").then(
                        (m) => m.WebviewModule
                    ),
            },
            {
                path: "messwerte/:id",
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import(
                        "~/app/monitordaten/daten-monitordaten/daten-monitordaten.module"
                    ).then((m) => m.DatenMonitordatenModule),
            },
        ]),
    ],
```

**functions to navigate between the siblings:**

```
goToMesswerte(monId:number){
        this.routerExt.navigate(['/monitorliste/messwerte/', monId], {skipLocationChange: true, transition: { name: 'slideRight' }})
    }

    goToWebview(monId:number){
        this.routerExt.navigate(['/monitorliste/webview/', monId ], {skipLocationChange: true, transition: { name: 'slideRight' }})
    }
```

As you can see I tried different parameters such as `skipLocationChange`,`replaceUrl` but neither did the expected

with the code above the app behaves like this:
[image: gif]
since it is nott possible to see, where I tapped on the screen here is what happens:
Im on the parent component

```
--> webview (child, navigated with top right button)  
--> messwerte (child, navigated with top right button)  
--> webview (child, navigated with top right button)  
--> messwerte (child, navigated with top right button)
```

```
<-- **pressing back** landing on webview  
<-- **pressing back** landing on messwerte for a short period, than beeing redirected to the parent
```

How can I achieve, to be directed to the parent component when pressing back, regardless of the sibling-component or how often I switched between them?

Answer (score 0):

Since I came up with an Idea that worked, here is my work-around:
on both child-components I just replaced the back-function with a navigation to the parent component.

Maybe there is a more elegant way, since a circular routing could be useful but for now my solution seems pleasant.